# Recommended AWS instance type for Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, amazon, amazon-web-services

I have a site that peaks out at less than 200 concurrent users maximum when it's busy and a steady 30 or so normally. I am planning an AWS migration from the current provider. I'd like to know what you would consider the ideal instance type for Magento. I am thinking the Memory Optimised instances would be pretty good for Magento as everyone knows how much Magento loves RAM. In another note, would there be much point in setting up a VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) for the traffic?

I am currently thinking to go to with a High Memory, EBS Optimised Instance (m2.4xlarge with 64GB ram, 8 vCPU & 26 ECU) - or should I focus more on CPU?

Comment: This is always a good one, there no is no correct answer, too many factors including theme speed, amount of code, number products, tiered pricing, number catagories. That is before you take in to account organic ranking and admin resource available. M1/3 Medium are the starting points, Magento is cpu based but you need multi-tiered caching and target sub 3s with ideal 1-2s dynamic page loads. You are thinking standard hosting single web/db server, the fun happens with cloud clusters (Nexcess style), but balancing technology & business is complex so we licensed the architecture instead.

Answer (score 14):

We run on multiple **c1.medium** instances that are auto-scaled with a **m1.db.small** [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds) instance, **cache.t1.micro** [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache) server for full page caching and [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront) **CDN** served from **two S3** sources (one for media, one for skin/js for more concurrent downloads per session).  We use S3FS for [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2) instances to connect to the S3s.   In addition, we use Lightspeed (now called Warp) full page caching, some custom block caching and Fooman Speedster Advanced.

We recently made some changes and found with the S3 system you need to set some symbolic links to expedite the process of PHP's `file_exists` function when a file is not present in a directory for the skin folder.  With that set up, we are getting page load times under 1 second (cached) and 2-3 seconds not cached.

I like the c1.medium because the cost (we usually run spot instances at <$0.07/hr...unless it's Christmas time).  Also, the compute optimized helps with the speed of processing all of the requests.  With memory levels set correctly in php.ini, we haven't run into memory problems on that instance.

You do more traffic than we do, but *caching is still the key*.  If you want to spend a little more, the current gen c3.large instances look enticing.  They offer good computing power,  decent memory, and SSD storage!

Be sure to set up any file system caching (like the cache for S3FS) on a local ephemeral drive to speed disk reads (and save money).  With the setup I described, the disk read shouldn't be the bottleneck because most data is coming from [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache) for the full page and [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront)/[S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for media.

I also highly recommend using a profiler to find and reduce bottlenecks.  That is how we lowered non-cached page speeds from 6 to 2 seconds because of the `file_exists` function and symlinks.

To answer the other part of your question...I'm not sure the [VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc) would help much, except to block bad bots/DNS attempts before they hit your servers.  Unless you have a ton of bad traffic, that shouldn't make a huge difference.

---

**Update 3/4/2017:**

This reply gets a decent amount of traffic and I've been getting some messages asking for help.   Since the original post was over three years ago, I don't remember all the details from back then.  Here's my current setup (*pretty much scroll through the AWS menu and add one or two of everything*):

- c3.large front-end servers running Apache (these work great for Magento and are relatively inexpensive)
- smaller back-end servers for API and admin
- Amazon [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs) for shared media storage (just implemented, but good so far)
- [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront) pointing to web servers for source
- No more full page caching (it wasn't giving enough speed enhancement
  to make up for the pain of hole-punching and dealing with added
  dynamic content on pages)
- [ElastiCache](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache) for caches and sessions
- [AWS Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/) for searches
- [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds) server for database

My current project is implementing scripts to ban IPs that are requesting too many pages or bad URLs (almost all of which are originating from Russia and Ukraine).  These can be >1000 requests/minute and cause major problems on several levels.  I'm looking at using something similar to this [fail2ban to Network ACL project](https://github.com/anthonymartin/aws-acl-fail2ban).  Speaking of malicious requests...**ALWAYS** move your admin folder to a different location that `/admin/` and set up `/downloader/.htaccess` to deny all but your IP.  Those are the two main URLs that these guys hit and the server load of them nailing those pages can cripple your server set up fast.

I feel that this site is not really small, but nowhere near large.  There are components that should be different depending on catalog size and traffic levels and the probability of traffic spikes.  The nice part is that you can set something like this up for around $100/mo, then scale quickly and easily by looking at loads from different services and add capacity where it is needed.

Comment: Can you explain me more your symlink fix for the S3 and file_exists problem with Magento ?

Comment: It's been 3 years...so I'm not real clear on how we did things back then.  I'm going to edit my reply to reflect what we do now.

Comment: Thank you for your update. So you remove S3. You do not have some bandwidth limitation with EFS ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. And what about your choices regarding server config? I see your frontend are on Apache. Which apache version? Same question for mysql, php (5.6)? It would be very helpful to know more about your experience on aws with M1. Maybe you also tested nginx/php-fpm on aws?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked far and wide for this answer and experimented on my own. The consensus, backed up by my experience, is that the minimum size needed is an m3.medium, which will set you back around $100 per month, but that is close enough in cost to a c3.large that I would go for that. Well, part of the beauty is that scaling up and down is easy and in your hands . (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)

It might not be a bad idea for you to look at the reserved instances. Unless your shop is fully busy at all hours, a medium utilization will probably do what you want and you can do that for a better price point.